# Fragment in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I am working on `Fragments`.  `Fragment1` contains `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` has 3 Fragments. when ever I call `Fragment1` `ViewPager` works fine. But if I replace `Fragment1` with other Fragment `Fragment2` and returns back to `Fragment1` using backButton. `ViewPager` displays nothing. All 3 fragments are added to fragment but `onCreateView()` is not called and there is no UI for these 3 fragments.  I am using  `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for `ViewPager`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post your code so that we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the `Fragment` which is calling your `ViewPager`'s pages. Try to use [`getChildFragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) instead.

Comment: Just had to ask, the answer was waiting for you ;). Have a good day !